Is it a good idea to have all the join conditions between tables or just use the primary/foreign key in JOIN for MySQL?
I have two tables where there are additional keys which I could use to filter rows.
Here is an example...
id is the primary key and tax_id is another commonly indexed column. tab2.tab1_id is not unique. There can be multiple rows in tab2 which match to a row in tab1.
tab1: id, tax_id
tab2: id, tab1_id, tax_id, state_tax_id
My question is.. which of the following usage is better.
id not present in any composite indexes. Tax_id is an indexed column.
#1
SELECT -some_cols-
  FROM tab1 t1
 INNER JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.tab1_id
 WHERE ......
;

#2
SELECT -same_cols-
  FROM tab1 t1
 INNER JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.tab1_id AND t1.tax_id = t2.tax_id
 WHERE .....
;


is t2.tab1_id unique? Is there lines where t1.id=t2.tab1_id but t1.tax_id<>t2.tax_id?

No its not unique. There can be multiple rows in tab2 with tab1_id

usually you add a index on all columns in join and where, to increase speed

MySQL doesnt like compound indexing PK/FK with other columns as PK/FK are indexed individually by MySQL when they are created. The question is regarding best usage of already indexed columns.


PRIMARY KEY is an INDEX.  It provides a unique access into the data.  There can be only one PK on a table.
FOREIGN KEY generates an INDEX if you don't already have a suitable one.  It can also provide "cascading deletes, etc.; personally, I don't like using it for such.
INDEX (of any kind) is (normally) a "B+Tree" that provides fast lookup of a single row, plus efficient scanning of a "range".  (Exceptions:  FULLTEXT and SPATIAL.)
UNIQUE is INDEX plus a uniqueness constraint.  The constraint prevents inserting a row with identical key values.
"Key" and "index" are synonyms.
For good JOIN performance, you must have a suitable INDEX.

For ON t1.id=t2.tab1_id, have

for t1, index on id
for t2, index on tab1_id

Assuming t1 had PRIMARY KEY(id), then all you need to do is make sure t2 has an index starting with tab1_id.
For t1.id=t2.tab1_id AND t1.tax_id = t2.tax_id, have a this 'composite' index:
t2:  INDEX(tab1.id, tax_id)  -- the order does not matter.

If you have a WHERE clause, let's see it; it may further change what I have said.
"Advice":

Your title begs for a "NATURAL JOIN" -- It is not good practice to assume the JOIN can figure out what to do based on FOREIGN KEYs.
Indexes (of any kind) are for performance.
Don't use FOREIGN until you understand it better.
Every table must have exactly one PRIMARY KEY.
When uniqueness is needed, use either PRIMARY or UNIQUE.
Don't specify an index in more than one way.
Look at each query to see if an existing index will help its performance.  If no index helps, create a new index.
If all your tables are "tiny", indexes don't matter much; if you have some huge tables (millions or billions of rows), indexes are vital to performance.
A "composite" index is an index with multiple columns.  Your second example begs for a composite index for the JOIN.
The Optimizer will effectively start with the WHERE clause to see which table to "begin" with; then it will move on to the JOIN.  This may become clearer after you provide a complete SELECT.
See my blog:  Index Cookbook


Thank you for the suggestions of adding a composite index to make the second query more efficient. PK and FK details are already mentioned in the description for your purview.
The question was which of the above two usages are better and why?

@Raja - My 3rd bullet item was intended to answer that.  Any index (INDEX, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY) is equivalent.

Thank you for the clarification. We have three choices here, use one of the indexes or use both of them. My question still remains unanswered. Which way is the best in MySQL and why.

@Raja - See if my rewrite clarified things enough.  Also, look around this and other places (e.g., StackOverflow) for examples.

Its thrilling to meet some one whose page I was following for my index clarifications from some time. My question is not regarding what index I need to create/update or change. My question is just regarding benefit of (not) using additional indexed column in the join.

@Raja - t1.id=t2.tab1_id AND t1.tax_id = t2.tax_id implies that both tests are needed for the JOIN.  If t1.id=t2.tab1_id suffices, don't confuse the reader.  Meanwhile, it is hard to imagine a situation where the Optimizer would be helped by the former.

Thank you. That is the suggestion I was looking for assuming Reader is a part of MySQL executor.
